# How to know differentiation of the function at zero

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2+|x|}$.
Can anyone tell me that this function is differential at zero or not?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to work out the limit by hand? $f'(x)=\lim (f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{x^2}{2+x}=0$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{x^2}{2-x}=0$$

So, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

$$f'(0^+)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2+x}-0}{x-0}=0$$
$$f'(0^-)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2-x}-0}{x-0}=0$$

Thus, it is differentiable and its derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for a good explanation

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h}{2+|h|}=0$ so it's differentiable and derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Even more general: if $f(x) = g(x)x^2$ with $g$ bounded, then
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)x^2}{x} =
\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)x = 0.
$$

Comment: thank you very much for a good explanation